# How to embed a redirection url to a website? (in React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, web, url, text

I would like to integrate this text in my app "https://www.google.com". When we click on it I will want the mobile browser to open and display the website. How to do this? I am novice, any help would be appreciate.

```js
<TouchableOpacity>
<View>
    <Text style={{color: 'grey', fontSize: 17, fontFamily:'Arial', fontStyle: 'bold', textAlign: 'center', 
    marginTop: 6, marginLeft: 25, marginBottom: 20}}> 
                https://www.google.com/
    </Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to wrap Text inside a View and then inside TouchableOpacity, for a Text itself has onPress property. Avoid unnecessary nesting of elements.

```
<Text style={{color: 'grey',
 fontSize: 17,
 fontFamily:'Arial',
 fontStyle: 'bold',
 textAlign: 'center', 
        marginTop: 6,
 marginLeft: 25,
 marginBottom: 20}}
 onPress = {() => {Linking.openURL('https://google.com')}}> 
  https://www.google.com/ /* Whatever appropriate text you want to display */
  </Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to official [React Native Linking documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking):

> If you are using the managed expo-cli workflow, see the guide on [Linking](https://docs.expo.io/guides/linking/?redirected) in the Expo documentation for the appropriate alternative.

And this page says:

> Often WebBrowser is a better option because it's a modal within your app and users can easily close out of it and return to your app.

So you can also use this one:

```
<Text style={{
  color: 'grey',
  fontSize: 17,
  fontFamily:'Arial',
  fontStyle: 'bold',
  textAlign: 'center', 
  marginTop: 6,
  marginLeft: 25,
  marginBottom: 20
 }}
 onPress = {() => {WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://google.com')}}> 
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still an option but in past i used this https://github.com/obipawan/react-native-hyperlink

For sure working solution is to split your text and the link part put like this

```js
<Text onPress={ ()=> Linking.openURL('https://google.com') } >Google.com</Text>
```

Comment: It's strange the text doesn't appear.. it's like I didn't put anything.

Comment: Please follow the steps from here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking

Comment: Sure, first what platform are you currently working ios or android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) component exposed by [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/)

**Step#01** Import Linking Component

```
 import { Linking } from 'react-native';
```

**Step#02** Use this with **onPress** prop of component.

```
 <Pressable onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://google.com')} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import { Linking } from 'react-native';

 ...

<TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop: 10, justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ececec',
    marginHorizontal: '25%',
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,marginBottom:20,       

  }}
  onPress={() => {
    Linking.openURL('https://www.google.com/')
  }}>
 
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: 'black' }}>
  Google
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: this is a code only answer. You can improve it by adding an explanation to it and doing something about the formatting.